# how to convert complex nested join sql query into Active Record rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I created a SQL query and ran it successfully. This query returns the record that has the last transaction_time in each group.

```
Select s.id, s.location_id 
From sales_transactions s 
    INNER JOIN (
        Select location_id, MAX(transaction_time) AS lastest 
        From sales_transactions 
        Group By location_id) s1 
ON s.location_id = s1.location_id     
   AND s1.lastest = s.transaction_time
```

I used ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute to run above query successfully. Now, I want to convert this SQL query into Active Record query in Rails 3. I did searched many questions here, however, because of the aggregate function in my sub query I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
SalesTransaction.select('id', 'location_id', 'max(transaction_time) AS lastest').group(:location_id)
```

or a little bit different but the same result (plus faster):

```
SalesTransaction.order(:transaction_time).group(:location_id)
```

Comment: I tried and it return error: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "sales_transactions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

Comment: Please provide your models and the schemas.